# Does the Pokemon need to be the same for the Masuda method in X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm trying the Masuda Method for shiny Charmander; does the Pokemon have to be exactly the same Pokemon for the increased chance?.

I'm currently breeding a Korean Charmander with an English Charizard - would I have to evolve it to be a Charizard? Or does it just have to be in the evolution line for a better chance?

Also, I see a lot of people getting shinies (and I have 4 shinies myself), so I was thinking, is the chance of finding one better? (If it is its probably 1/4000 instead of 1/8000.)

Answer (score 3):

No, the only requirements for the Masuda method is that the breeding pair are from different regions. As long as that requirement is met, you can breed your Korean Charmander with an English Charizard, English Charmander, or English Ditto, and the improved shiny chance remains the same.

Comment: Breeding a Charmander with another Charmander (same species) *would* decrease the time to produce an egg, however.

Comment: It's also worth noting it usually still takes over 100 eggs to get the shiny. So it's still a game of patience.

Answer (score 1):

The increased shiny encounter rates are likely because of the Shiny Charm. It's a key item that triples shiny encounter rate, obtained by seeing the entire National Dex, sans events. When combined with the Masuda Method, you get a 1 in 1024 chance of finding shinies.

I hatched a shiny Charmander last weekend without even trying, and the day after, found a shiny Serviper while horde hunting HA Taillow. The effort of getting the charm is worth it.

Comment: It should be noted that the shiny charm has not been proven to work with Masuda Method yet. That is, for X and Y